# Testing which is greater but value changes

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset df which I would like to test at the indicator, how many of the value is greater than the testing threshold. For example for A, I want to test how many of it exceeds threshold value1 of -1, how many exceeds threshold value2 of -0.5, threshold value3 of 1 and threshold value4 of 2. The thing is my testing threshold is different for each A,B and C. How should I loop it?

```
   df >
    A     B       C     
    1     5       2     
    2    12       3     
    3    -1       4    
    4     0       6    
    5    -9     -13    
    6    0.1      2     
    7    1        3
```

Testing threshold

```
 ID    value1 value2 value3 value4
 A         -1   -0.5    1      2  
 B          1    6      9     12  
 C          3    3.2    3.4    3.5
```

Desired Output for A

```
ID    value1 value2 value3 value4
A        7       7       6      5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming testing threshold is stored in dataframe called `test`, you could split it row-wise  and use `Map` to find output for each `ID` how many values are greater than each threshold.

```
Map(function(x, y) colSums(sapply(y, `<`, x)), df, asplit(test[-1], 1))

#$A
#value1 value2 value3 value4 
#     7      7      6      5 

#$B
#value1 value2 value3 value4 
#     2      1      1      0 

#$C
#value1 value2 value3 value4 
#     2      2      2      2
```

Comment: May I know if my data is not in the same order as test, will this work too? For example if my df is (A,C,B) instaed of (A,B,C). Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you can order `df` as `test` by replacing `df` in the answer with `df[test$ID]`